# JAXB Unmarshalling changes the namespaces

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML that I have built for the security token. These contain WS-Trust based namespaces, but when I unmarshal this XML to create `RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollection` object, it replaces the namespaces with namespaces like `ns1`, `ns2`, `ns3` etc.

Is there a way I can unmarshal the XML without changing the namespaces and namespaces' prefixes from input XML?

This is the way I have been trying:

```
class XMLReaderWithoutNamespace extends StreamReaderDelegate
{
    public XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(XMLStreamReader reader)
    {
        super(reader);
    }

    @Override
    public String getAttributeNamespace(int arg0)
    {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getNamespaceURI()
    {
        return "";
    }
}

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Source xmlSource = new DOMSource(inputXML);
            Result outputTarget = new StreamResult(outputStream);
            TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(xmlSource, outputTarget);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
            XMLStreamReader xsr = XMLInputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamReader(is);
            XMLReaderWithoutNamespace xr = new XMLReaderWithoutNamespace(xsr);

            JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollectionType.class);
            Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
            JAXBElement<RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollectionType> root = (JAXBElement<RequestSecurityTokenResponseCollectionType>) unmarshaller
                .unmarshal(new StreamSource(new StringReader(sb.toString())));
        response = root.getValue();
```

My package-info.java is

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-trust/200512", elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package org.oasis_open.docs.ws_sx.ws_trust._200512;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this by building the entire Security Token based on my object factory. Used `JAXB` to `marshall` each element. This created the required namespaces and their prefixes for final `response`